# How to make tsc only load the types used from node_modules when using yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to improve my typescript project compilation time.

I use yarn workspaces, where I have several projects, here is my basic file architecture:

```
node_modules
packages
  server
  client
```

When I use `tsc --diagnostics`, on the `server` package here is what I have (second run with `--incremental`):

```
Files:              5269
Lines:           2022462
Nodes:           4803555
Identifiers:     1727459
Symbols:          921382
Types:                78
Instantiations:        0
Memory used:    1393114K
I/O read:          1.62s
I/O write:         0.00s
Parse time:       14.15s
Bind time:         3.31s
Check time:        0.00s
Emit time:         0.00s
Total time:       17.46s
```

From what I understand it spends a lot of time parsing files, so I ran `tsc --listFiles`.

I realized it parses a lot of type files from `node_modules` that the `server` package does not depend on. They're actually dependencies of my `client` package.

Is there a way to load only the files that my `server` package actually depends on?

Answer (score 1):

You could define individual tsconfig.json's for `server` and `client` utilizing [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) and [exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) to match only the files actually needed.